# Making lavalamp start on right

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using a lavalamp script for a navigation.
http://jsfiddle.net/ripsraps/cwdJ3/1/
(it's not rendering correctly on fiddle)

The lavalamp starts on the left side.
Is it any way of making it start on the right side?

Comment: Looks like your background image is pointing to the server on which it is hosted. Change `background-image: url(../../images/lava.gif);` to have the complete URL so we can see this in action

Comment: if you want to see how it looks; check out http://www.millersmartialarts.no/